# drop database via bash with dash in database-name

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell, terminal

I have a variable in a script with the list of folder names with dash in their names

```
DBDIR="some directory"
dbdash=`ls -l $DBDIR | egrep '^d' | grep '.-.' | awk '{print $9}'`
```

And I want to drop every database with the same names with the folders in the variable "dbdash"

```
dbhype=($dbdash)
    for dbtry in ${!dbhype[*]}
        do            
            mysqladmin -u$dbUser -p$dbPass 'drop database if exists `'${dbhype[$dbtry]}'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
    done
```

But this error came out after running the script

> mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'drop database if exists `folder_name` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLAT'

How can I delete these databases using script? Please help.

Comment: Don't parse `ls`, and don't try to store a list of files in a flat string. `cd "$DBDIR"; dbhype=( *-*/ )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backquotes are for executing commands; you just want to quote the value (although the way you construct `dbhype`, quoting is too late to do you any good).

```
cd "DBDIR"
for dbtry in *-*/; do
    mysqladmin -u "$dbUser" -p "$dbPass" "drop database if exists '$dbtry'"
done
```

Comment: thank you  @chepner for this answer. i tried using this and edited a bit of it. I use this:

`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e 'drop database if exists `'$dbtry'`'`

instead of:

`mysqladmin -u "$dbUser" -p "$dbPass" "drop database if exists '$dbtry'"`


and it worked!